# Multi-site get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') referring to sub-folder

Tags: multisite, themes

I am using multi-site instance, but want each site to use the same themes throughout. When I reference

```
get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');
```

I was expecting:

```
http://domain.com/mainsite/wp-content/themes/my-theme
```

instead I get:

```
http://domain.com/mainsite/subsite1/wp-content/themes/my-theme
http://domain.com/mainsite/subsite2/wp-content/themes/my-theme
```

Is their a WP function I can use to get the main them directory only, and not have WP include each site's directory name?

Comment: I suspect that you're seeing the proper behaviour.  Multisite sets up those virtual paths, and then your `.htaccess` file will point them to the correct filesystem locations. Have you tried [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri), as recommended on the [Codex page for `get_bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo)?

Comment: I'm sure it is the working way that WP implemented it. Is there any existing workaround for that? Other than having to hack it myself? Yes, I have tried http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri and it gives me the same result =/

Answer (score 1):

Okay I avoided the lazy way out =)

For others that have my particular site requirements, here's my workaround, of simply creating my own custom method in functions.php:

```
function mysite_get_theme_directory_uri() {
    // chop up the url from get_stylesheet directory
    $parsedUrl = parse_url(get_stylesheet_directory_uri());

    // chop up the 'path' index value
    $path = $parsedUrl['path'];
    // make it an array
    $parsedPath = explode('/', $path);
    // remove the 3rd element of the path's array, which is the site name
    unset($parsedPath[2]);

    // put that path array back into a string
    $themesPath = implode("/", $parsedPath);

    // return full URL
    return $parsedUrl['scheme'] . '://' . $parsedUrl['host'] . $themesPath;
}
```